# Magento 2: How to put products on separate rows in export order XML?

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, xml, export

I want to display product names in separate rows along with their weight and sku's when I export orders using xml.

Here is my custom code(ConvertToXml.php) where I added sku and weight:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Custom\OrderExport\Model\Export;

use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\DocumentInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Convert\Excel;
use Magento\Framework\Convert\ExcelFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;

/**
 * Class ConvertToXml
 */
class ConvertToXml extends \Magento\Ui\Model\Export\ConvertToXml
{
//     /**
//      * Returns Filters with options
//      *
//      * @return array
//      */
//     protected function getOptions()
//     {
//         if (!$this->options) {
//             $this->options = $this->metadataProvider->getOptions();
//         }
//         return $this->options;
//     }

//     /**
//      * Returns DB fields list
//      *
//      * @return array
//      * @throws LocalizedException
//      */
//     protected function getFields()
//     {
//         if (!$this->fields) {
//             $component = $this->filter->getComponent();
//             $this->fields = $this->metadataProvider->getFields($component);
//         }
//         return $this->fields;
//     }

//     /**
//      * Returns row data
//      *
//      * @param DocumentInterface $document
//      * @return array
//      * @throws LocalizedException
//      */
//     public function getRowData(DocumentInterface $document)
//     {
//         return $this->metadataProvider->getRowData($document, $this->getFields(), $this->getOptions());
//     }

//     /**
//      * Returns XML file
//      *
//      * @return array
//      * @throws LocalizedException
//      */
//    public function getXmlFile()
// {
//     $component = $this->filter->getComponent();


//     $name = md5(microtime());
//     $file = 'export/'. $component->getName() . $name . '.csv';

//     $this->filter->prepareComponent($component);
//     $this->filter->applySelectionOnTargetProvider();
//     $dataProvider = $component->getContext()->getDataProvider();
//     //exit(get_class($dataProvider));
//     $fields = $this->metadataProvider->getFields($component);

//     $options = $this->metadataProvider->getOptions();

//     $this->directory->create('export');
//     $stream = $this->directory->openFile($file, 'w+');
//     $stream->lock();
//     $stream->writeCsv($this->metadataProvider->getHeaders($component));
//     $i = 1;
//     $searchCriteria = $dataProvider->getSearchCriteria()
//         ->setCurrentPage($i);
//     $totalCount = (int) $dataProvider->getSearchResult()->getTotalCount();
//     while ($totalCount > 0) {
//         $items = $dataProvider->getSearchResult()->getItems();
//         //  echo '<pre>'; print_r(get_class($dataProvider)); exit;
//         foreach ($items as $item) {
//             if($component->getName()=='sales_order_grid') {
//                 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
//                 $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($item->getEntityId());
//                 $items123 = $order->getAllItems();
//                 $skuArray = [];
//                 $nameArray = [];
//                 $qtyArray = [];
//                 $weightArray = [];

//                 foreach ($items123 as $key => $item1) {
//                     $skuArray[] = $item1->getSku();
//                     $nameArray[] = $item1->getName();
//                     $qtyArray[] = $item1->getQtyOrdered();
//                     $weightArray[] = $item1->getWeight();
//                 }
//                 $export_status = implode("\n", $skuArray);
//                 $item->setSku($export_status);
//                 $productName = implode("\n", $nameArray);
//                 $item->setProductName($productName);
//                 $productWeight = implode("\n", $weightArray);
//                 $item->setWeight($productWeight);
//                 $total = $order->getGrandTotal();
//                 $item->setWeight($total);
//                 // print_r($qtyArray); exit;
//                 $productqty = implode(", ", $qtyArray);
//                 $item->setQty($productqty);
//             }
//             $this->metadataProvider->convertDate($item, $component->getName());
//             $stream->writeCsv($this->metadataProvider->getRowData($item, $fields, $options));
//         }
//         $searchCriteria->setCurrentPage(++$i);
//         $totalCount = $totalCount - '20';
//     }
//     $stream->unlock();
//     $stream->close();

//     return [
//         'type' => 'filename',
//         'value' => $file,
//         'rm' => true  // can delete file after use
//     ];
// }


    /**
     * @param string $componentName
     * @param array $items
     * @return void
     */
    protected function prepareItems($componentName, array $items = [])
    {
        foreach ($items as $document) {
            $component = $this->filter->getComponent();

            if($component->getName()=='sales_order_grid') {
                    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                    $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($document->getEntityId());
                    $items123 = $order->getAllItems();
                    $skuArray = [];
                    $nameArray = [];
                    $qtyArray = [];
                    $weightArray = [];

                    foreach ($items123 as $key => $item1) {
                        $skuArray[] = $item1->getSku();
                        $nameArray[] = $item1->getName();
                        $qtyArray[] = $item1->getQtyOrdered();
                        $weightArray[] = $item1->getWeight();
                    }

                    // $sku = implode("&", $skuArray);
                    // $String='';
                    // $newString='';
                    // $maxCharacterCount=23;
                    // foreach ($sku as $key => $value) {
                    //     $strlen=strlen($String);
                    //     if($strlen<=$maxCharacterCount){
                    //             $String.=' '.$value;

                    //         }else{
                    //             $newString.=$String.' '.$value.'\n';
                    //             $String='';

                    //         }
                    //     }
                    //     $finalString= $newString.$String;
                        // echo $finalString;

                    $skuu = implode("\n", $skuArray);

                    var_dump($document->getData()); exit;
                    $document->setSku($skuu);
                    $productName = implode("\n", $nameArray);
                    $document->setProductName($productName);
                    $productWeight = implode("\n", $weightArray);
                    $document->setWeight($productWeight);
                    $total = $order->getGrandTotal();
                    $document->setGrandTotal($total);
                    $productqty = implode(", ", $qtyArray);
                    $document->setQtyOrdered($productqty);
                    $document->setItemQuantity($productqty);
                    $document->setQty($productqty);
                    $document->setQuantity($productqty);


                    // $removeFieldsArr = array('billing_address', 'shipping_address');

                    // foreach ($document as $key=>$val) {
                    //     if (in_array($val, $removeFieldsArr)) {

                    //         unset($document[$val]);
                    //     }
                    // }
                     
                    $this->metadataProvider->convertDate($document, $componentName);

                } else {
                    $this->metadataProvider->convertDate($document, $componentName);
                }
        }
    }
}
```